# What is postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map use for?

Tags: security, configuration, postfix

What is the meaning of `postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map` in postscreen (postfix) ?
I've read from documentation:

> if your DNSBL queries have a "secret" in the domain name, you must censor this information from the postscreen(8) SMTP replies ([1](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html))

And from manual:

> A mapping from actual DNSBL domain name which includes a secret password, to the DNSBL domain name that postscreen will reply with when it rejects mail. When no mapping is found, the actual DNSBL domain will be used. ([2](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html))

I don't understand about *a secret password* means, how a DNS domain name will include a password?

Could you explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some non-free DNSBLs give customers a secret DNS label to insert between the base domain and the query target (i.e. octet-reversed IP or domain name) as a form of authentication. Obviously this "secret" isn't well-protected from snooping by actors who can sniff the DNS traffic, but as a practical matter it is safe enough for most DNSBLs' needs. For so, the "postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map" feature can hide "password" information in DNSBL domain names.

In other words, when postscreen rejects mail, usually a spam, its SMTP reply contains the DNSBL domain name, so the "postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map" feature (i.e. a configuration parameter) in [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/postfix.1.html) can hide "password" information for those "some non-free DNSBLs". In addition, it can hide the DNSBLs names that are used in response to emails that are rejected.